# How can I use the LIKE clause on two columns while prioritizing one of them?

Tags: mysql

Say I have two columns... **title** and **description**. I would like to write a command to return all rows where a search term (for the sake of the example I will use "**toilet**") is present. I would like the results to first display any rows that have "toilet" in the title. Then after that I would like to display the rows that have "toilet" in the description (but not also in the title). How can I do this? All I know how to do is search without taking into account any column prioritization:

```
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE title LIKE "%toilet%" OR description LIKE "%toilet%"
```

Comment: ``order by `title` like '%toilet%'``. the boolean result of the `like` will be sorted as if it was integer 0/1.

Comment: @MarcB So you need a `desc` or a `not`

Comment: depends on which one you want prioritized, and how. toilet present: order desc, toilet not present: order asc

Comment: The question states what the priority should be.

Comment: You can as well use `UNION` here grouping two resultsets.

Comment: I think `union` might be overkill. I think Marc B should put his comments as an answer.

Comment: @Martin, yes but a alternative though.

Comment: So I just add this to the end?